# How to parse date days that contain "st", "nd", "rd", or "th"?

Tags: python, date, python-2.7

I have a string like this

```
"1st January 2014"
```

I want to parse it into a `datetime.date`. I can do this:

If the date is `1 January 2014`
I make this: `replace(' ','')` then `datetime.strptime(SecondDateString, "%d%B%Y").date()`

But this doesn't work when the day has `st`, `nd`, `rd`, or `th`.

**Edit:**
you may say that I myself remove the `st`, `nd`, `rd`, or `th` and then use my own way above, yes this is a solution but I am asking if python has already had something for me.

Comment: Not helpful ?? `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644417/python-format-datetime-with-st-nd-rd-th-english-ordinal-suffix-like`

Comment: @PriyankPatel Unfortunately that is django specific...

Comment: @PriyankPatel no not helpful, i already check it while i was searching on google

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `regex` to replace `st`, `nd`, `rd`, `th`  with an empty string:

```
import re
def solve(s):                                             
    return re.sub(r'(\d)(st|nd|rd|th)', r'\1', s)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> datetime.strptime(solve('1st January 2014'), "%d %B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime(solve('3rd March 2014'), "%d %B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 3, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime(solve('2nd June 2014'), "%d %B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 2, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime(solve('1st August 2014'), "%d %B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: For anyone wanting use this function in pandas to convert a series try ```df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(solve)```

Comment: use `\d+` instead of `\d` so it works for days of month bigger then 9

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dateutil.parser` module

```
date1 = "1st January 2014"
dateutil.parser.parse(date1)
>> datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

You can check full documentation [from here](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

Comment: Don't forget `import dateutil.parser`

Comment: @FallenAngel this is amazing! But why oh why does python have both `datetime.strptime()` and also `dateutil.parser.parse()`?

Comment: @BLimitless because datetime is a python core module while dateutil is a 3rd party library.

Comment: @fallenangel Ah, that makes sense. I thought it was built in because I didn't have to pop install it  It must have been installed automatically in my anaconda distribution. Thank you.