# How to handle spelled out days in strptime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have an array of dates that is formatted like so:

```
['October 22nd, 2019', 'February 8th, 2020', 'July 31st, 2020', 'September 21st, 2020', ...]
```

I'd like to turn it into datetime objects using strptime, but I can't figure out how to hand the spelled out parts of the days, e.g. `22nd` or `8th` and it doesn't say in [the format documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

The following works when there's no written out part of the day:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_obj = datetime.striptime('October 22, 2019', '&B &d, &Y')
```

But I can't figure out how to parse a string that has the day written out:

```
in: dt_obj = datetime.striptime('October 22nd, 2019', '&B &d, &Y')
out: ValueError: time data 'October 22nd, 2019' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'
```

What's the proper format for this? Thank you!

Comment: Is this helpful?  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496246/how-to-parse-date-days-that-contain-st-nd-rd-or-th)

Comment: Yes, very, thank you! Of course, now I'd like to know why there's two separate built in datetime parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> e.g. `22nd` or `8th` and it doesn't say in [the format
> documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

You got it right, it is not mentioned in documentation because there is no such formats, one way you can parse them is by using `regex`, and converting those date strings to something for which Python's `datetime` has the format for.

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime

[datetime.strptime(x, '%B %d %Y') for x in [' '.join(re.findall('^\w+|\d+',each)) for each in ['October 22nd, 2019', 'February 8th, 2020', 'July 31st, 2020', 'September 21st, 2020']]]

#output:
[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 21, 0, 0)]
```