# Python how to return date as words?

Tags: python, date, time, return

I've got a date in the format day=30, month=11, year=2014. How can I use python to return this in a worded format? Example Sunday 30th November 2014. I can't find any datetime format that this works for...

Comment: can you show us an actual example of your datetime object?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following format for [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
In [1]: from datetime import date

In [2]: date(day=30, month=11, year=2014).strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
Out[2]: 'Sunday 30 November 2014'
```

Adding the proper suffix to the day number is more complicated:

- [python format datetime with "st", "nd", "rd", "th" (english ordinal suffix) like PHP's "S"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3644417/1258041)
- [Date Ordinal Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/739241/1258041)

Comment: In addition, `%dth` will give `30th` instead of `30` (only makes sense for dates that end with 'th')

Comment: Link to python docs with complete list of `strftime ` formatting directives https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, but unfortunately that will be incorrect for days from `1` to `3` and some others.

Comment: Yeah I added that moments after