# giving numbers ordinal suffixes in python

Tags: python

I am new to python so all help would be highly appreciated!
I have learnt to use the enumerate method in my code, which gives a list tuples e.g. 'i like football' giving the word football position '3'. 
My problem is that Once I have the list and the code written out with enumerate function, I am trying to give the number given an ordinal suffix, e.g. '3' being given 'rd' and '2' being given 'nd'.
Here is my code so far:

```
word = str(raw_input("Enter Word: "))

food = " i like computer science"
food2 = food.split()
for (num, x) in enumerate(list(food2)):
  if word == x:
    print num
```

Comment: [this may be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644417/python-format-datetime-with-st-nd-rd-th-english-ordinal-suffix-like)

Comment: as it stands, i dont believe there to be anything that is built in. the datetime module can be used in a kind of hacky way by passing the index in as a date and calling `strftime` to return it in an ordinal format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the [natural](http://natural.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) package to do this (and more).

```
pip install natural
```

Then using this code, you can print out ordinals:

```
>>> from natural import number
>>> number.ordinal(3)
u'3rd'
>>> number.ordinal(1234567)
u'1234567th'
```

Comment: i missed the ordinal part - sorry

Comment: i've tried entering the code into my python IDLE, which is running python 3 and it is returning an error message?

Comment: i get the 'invalid syntax' on the 'pip install natural' line

Comment: That is not done in your python code. That is done from your system's command line.