# Extract expected Date from String by using datetime

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, datetime, python-3.6

String :- ***"Today is November 19th, 2019."***

Output :- November 19th, 2019

I tried this :-

```
datetime.strptime(re.search((January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|Octomber|November|December) \d{1,2}(th|st|rd), \d{4}",String).group(), "%B %d, %Y")
```

But it shows me Error like :-

> ValueError: time data 'November 11th, 2019' does not match format '%B %d(th|st|rd), %Y'

Can anyone help me in this , Where I am wrong .

Comment: `Octomber` seems odd to me. Your pattern should be in quotes `r'pattern'`

Comment: Perhaps this page might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644417/python-format-datetime-with-st-nd-rd-th-english-ordinal-suffix-like

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime` formatting does not support regex-like patterns, so you should build a string of a fixed format first for it parse.

You can use `re.sub` instead to extract only the month, day and year from the string and reassemble them into a space-delimited string before passing to `datetime.strptime` for parsing:

```
datetime.strptime(re.sub(r'.*\b(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|Octomber|November|December) (\d{1,2})(?:th|st|rd), (\d{4})\b.*', r'\1 \2 \3', String), "%B %d %Y")
```